# Where do the function pointers point to in struct "proto_ops"?

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, function-pointers, getsockopt

In Linux kernel, I find the system call `getsockopt` finally calls `sock->ops->getsockopt` ([code here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c?v=3.11#L1937)). And `sock->ops` is a struct called `proto_ops`. This struct contains many function pointers such as [`getsockopt`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/net.h?v=3.11#L156) and I am wondering where it points to - I didn't find the place initiates this struct.

I'm using IPv4 and TCP for the system call and it may have some certain implementation functions to call here.

Any insights would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an IPv4 socket, the ops will be one of the structures [`inet_stream_ops`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c?v=3.11#L936), [`inet_dgram_ops`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c?v=3.11#L964), [`inet_sockraw_ops`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c?v=3.11#L995) defined in `net/ipv4/af_inet.c` (unless you're using something weird like SCTP that has its own ops defined elsewhere). To see how those pointers get there, look at [`inet_create`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c?v=3.11#L277) in the same file, which is [called from `__sock_create` as `pf->create()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c?v=3.11#L1327).

To see how *that* pointer gets there, note that `inet_create` is the `create` member of a struct called `inet_family_ops` which is [passed to `sock_register()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c?v=3.11#L1716), causing it to be placed in the `net_families` array which is consulted when a socket is created.

Functions with `register` in their names are a good thing to look for when you want to see how different kernel components are connected.

Now back to `getsockopt`. If you look at where the `getsockopt` pointer actually goes, in all 3 of the `inet_*_ops` structs it points to `sock_common_getsockopt` for the `getsockopt` function.

`sock_common_getsockopt` in `net/core/sock.c` isn't very interesting. It just extracts a `struct sock` from a `struct socket` and then calls `sk->sk_prot->getsockopt`. So next you'll be wondering where *that* comes from.

It comes from the next layer up. I'm going to assume TCP as an example.

In `net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c` there's a `struct proto tcp_prot` in which the `getsockopt` member points to `tcp_getsockopt`, a function defined in `net/ipv4/tcp.c`. It implements `SOL_TCP` options itself, and for others, it calls the `getsockopt` method from another ops structure called `icsk_af_ops`. That brings us back to `net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c` where `struct inet_connection_sock_af_ops ipv4_specific` has `getsockopt` pointing to `ip_getsockopt`.

`ip_getsockopt` is in `net/ipv4/ip_sockglue.c` and it calls `do_ip_getsockopt` in the same file, which is where the `SOL_IP` options are actually handled.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification! I learnt a lot from it. So I add a print statement to `sock_common_getsockopt` and `tcp_getsockopt`, surprisingly the I got the output from `sock_common_getsockopt` but not `tcp_getsockopt`. (I'm using `SOL_TCP` actually.) But I get the output from another function called `security_socket_getsockopt` in `security/security.c`. Do you have any insight why is this method called? I create the socket by `sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` and I think it's an IPv4 socket used by TCP.

Comment: And I find this function calls `security_ops->socket_getsockopt`, which is also a function pointer (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/security.h?v=3.13#L1656). Where might it point to?

Comment: Oh I worked it out - `security_socket_getsockopt` is called at the beginning at `sock_common_getsockopt` and the following function calls will terminate if this one exits abnormally.  Thank you so much!